# How to use Polkadot.js to parse the "aca to dot" bridge transaction?

Tags: polkadot, chainbridge

1. The transaction is like this: https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/14760951-1?event=14760951-43 ,
2. I want to get information as follows:
   (1) from and to account address,
   (2) the transfer money,
   (3) the transfer fee,
   (4) the transfer signature,
   (5) the transfer status: success or failed?

Comment: The message id is the hash of the message so you can't get it from that. If you have the passed messages then you can hash them and then find the match. With xcm v3, when sending messages they should create a send event with the message hash so that they can be matched up and also topics can be set on the message so that you can uniquely identify them though I've not yet tried this out. Also check out https://polkaholic.io/xcmmessages - they have done a lot of sleuthing to match up pre-xcm v3 messages through heuristics.